# macOS missing storage I should have Big Sur, How do I reclaim it?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, apple-silicon

It's getting unacceptable now, I do not understand where my Mac storage is, I'm supposed to have 500 GB of storage, and yet my Mac says I only have 219 GB.

Using an external disk viewer like Omniswepper, tells me that my main disk has used 402 GB, yet has 219 GB total. I am on Big Sur, Mac base M1 model. I've searched this issue over I'd go as far as saying hundreds of times because I didn't want to ask here and my answer was out there, but it's not.

How do I reclaim my missing Mac storage? I have no clue how I used 402 GB unaware and nowhere to be found

[image: Screenshot of the Drive List in Ominsweeper]

[image: Screenshot of the data allocation from System Settings > General > Storage]

Comment: 1) Do you use Time Machine for backup (with default 1hr backups)? 2) Are your Parallels VMs running? 3) Are the VMs excluded from backup? 4) Pease add the results of Terminal command `diskutil list`. 5) The Omnidisksweeper summary is nonsense for recent macOS - use DaisyDisk, scan as an administrator and drill down.